# Problema con llamado a dompdf

Tags: php, html, pdf

Buen dia

estaba viendo un tutorial de dompdf para instalarlo pero no encuentro tutos mas recientes y al colocar la sentencia `require_once 'dompdf-master/src/autoloader.php';` me da este error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les agradezco toda la ayuda

PD: no se si esta bien le require pero es los archivos que me dicen en los tutos no los tengo en mi libreria
gracias
si necesitan pantallazo de los items de la libreria que tengo me dicen pls
adjunto la estructura de las carpetas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
                    $codigo=utf8_decode($codigo);
                    $pdf = new Dompdf\Dompdf(); 
                    $dompdf->load_html($codigo);
                    ini:set("memory_limit","32M");
                    $dompdf->render();  
                    $dompdf->stream("ejemplo.pdf");
```

$codigo es el codigo html no se si esta bien por que fue lo que vi en el tuto

Comment: Efectivamente ahs eso que indicas al final para saber que tienes y verificar si te perdistes algo.

Comment: no entendi tu comentario

Comment: La carpeta **dompdf-master** está dentro de inventario?, sí estaría bien ver el pantallazo con la estructura de tus carpetas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas descargar el **dompdf** con todos sus archivos de configuración completos, baja la última versión desde este enlace: [Dompdf 0.8.1](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases/download/v0.8.1/dompdf_0-8-1.zip)

Luego importas la liberia con el autoload que viene en la caperta y esta listo para usar, ejemplo:

require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

$pdf = new Dompdf\Dompdf();

Comment: listo ya la descargue pero no se como hacer la validacion edito la pregunta con el codigo que tengo

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con validación?

Comment: el require y eso lo basico que hay que poner para que lo "transforme"

Comment: El archivo en el cual estas requiriendo a dompdf, ¿donde esta ubicado?, dame la ruta

Comment: no ya gracias ya pude jeje hen ahora tengo una complicaciones con el html pero no problem

Comment: Recuerda que al declarar la instancia de dompdf la estas asignando a la variable $pdf, entonces debes cambiar la variable $dompdf a $pdf.

Comment: ok gracias por la ayuda